# How to chain actions with Link in React Router?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am mapping through some values and outputting a Link for each value. When the user clicks the Link I would like to setContext ***before*** the 'to' part of the link is actioned. Is this possible? At the moment it seems with the code below both actions, the setting of the context and the linking in the router are done concurrently.

```
{ myTags && myTags.map(tag => (
    <li key={tag}>
        <button>
            <Link onClick={() => setTagContext(tag)} to={`/filter/${tagContext}`}>
                {tag}
            </Link>
        </button>
    </li>
))}
```

I can almost get the result I am looking for by using 'onmouseover' instead, but I'd rather use onClick. Is it possible?

Cheers,
Matt

Answer (score 4):

- Use the `button` instead. It's a better practice to use a button if it has an onClick event.
- Furthermore, you could simply use `history`  to update the URL.

```
const history = useHistory();

function handleLinkClick(tag) {
   setTagContext(tag);
   history.push(`/filter/${tagContext}`);
}

{ myTags && myTags.map(tag => (
    <li key={tag}>
        <button onClick={() => handleLinkClick(tag)}>
             {tag}
        </button>
    </li>
))}
```

Comment: Hello Prateek,

Thank you for your reply.  It's producing the same result, but strange behaviour (in my opinion). In the code below the console log outputs the default value, not the value of the tag:

function handleLinkClick(tag) {
    setTagContext(tag);
    console.log('handle value: ',tagContext)
    history.push(`/filter/${tagContext}`);
}

As if it's ignoring the setTagContext instruction.